# Getting the most out of Resharper - good tutorials/screencasts

Tags: resharper

I've just installed Resharper, and I really don't know how to use it "correctly".
I noticed that there are some demos and documents at their website, but I'm wondering..

..how did you learn to use it efficiently? Are there any other good resources(demos/tutorials)?

Comment: I suggest you rename the question to refer to Resharper instead of R#.  There is a Rebol language port to .NET called R#.

Comment: Another very good question closed as opinionable :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a [series of screencasts](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/ReSharper) on the [Dime Casts](http://dimecasts.net/) website which are quite good as an introduction.

There is also the [31 days of Resharper](http://blog.excastle.com/2007/01/31/blog-event-the-31-days-of-resharper/) and the [official demos](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/index.html) give you an idea of what's possible so you know to dive into the menu.

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains is now offering one free month of access to the ReSharper Fundamentals course on Pluralsight to license holders. See [Pluralsight and JetBrains Agreement](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/pluralsight-and-jetbrains-agreement/) for details.

> This isn't just any courseware, it's a complete 3 hour course on how
>   to better master ReSharper, created by James Kovacs, JetBrains Academy
>   Board Member and long-time ReSharper user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ReSharper Workshop](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-workshop) on GitHub.

It is a Visual Studio project that guids you through many features of ReSharper.